# How to add Label ( ex: 1,2,3..) to marker icon in mapbox in android

Tags: mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

How to add label into mapbox marker icon (not the infoWindow) in android studio.
here is the [Example of the marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Gmf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Mapbox IconGenerator.
See how to use it in :

[mapbox-gl issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/9365)

And see this sample :

[Mapbox Android Utils](https://github.com/mastrgamr/mapbox-android-utils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/mastrgamr/mbmapboxutils/ui/IconGenerator.java)